# React - How to pass data among parent - child AND among siblings at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, setstate

I have a component (LoginScreen). In that component I want to display my Login component as the first thing the user sees. When user clicks on sign up button, in my Loginscreen component, the Signup Component should be rendered instead. From the signup Component the user finds a button 'Back to Login' and when clicked, again the Login Component should be rendered insight the componentt Loginscreen. Im new to React and trying to follow tutorials about how to share data among parent/child and among siblings but am completely confused. Any help would be amazing!

```
    class Loginscreen extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
               status:false
            } 
                this.changeStatus = this.changeStatus.bind(this);
        }
     changeStatus(status) {
        this.setState({
          status: true
        });
      }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
         <Login status={this.state.status}/>
         <Signup status={this.state.status}/>
             <p>No account yet?</p>
            <button onClick={this.changeStatus}>Sign up</button>
          // if Signup Component is rendered insight Loginscreen, then this button should also not be rendered. 
          </div>
        )

       }
    }

    class Signup extends React.Component {
      ...
      //where can I even call this function in my case?
       handleChange() {
        const status:true;
        this.props.onClick(status);
      }
      ...
        <button><Link to='/loginscreen'>Back to Login</Link></button>
      ...
    }

    class Login extends React.Component {
      ...

      ...
    }
```

Comment: I believe this is where Redux http://redux.js.org/ will come into play. It allows all components to easily share the state of the application and all respond when state is changed.

Comment: I know, i don't know redux at all and as it comes to parent/child and sibling components, its possible to pass data among those so I wanted to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe you are looking for routing?

## Solution 1 (recommended):

Using [React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) to handle the routing and the [React-Router/Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-links) component will handle the switching.

## Solution 2:

Using a simple state routing, saving the view name in the parent component and display the view based on it, also passing a function to update this view:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   view: 'login' // its login because we want it to be the default
  } 
  this.changeView = this.changeView.bind(this);
 }
 changeView(view) {
  this.setState({
   view // ES6, if the key & value variable name the same, just type it once.
  });
 }
 
 render() {
  const { view } = this.state; // thats es6 destructuring, use it to make the variables clean instead of repeating the this.state/this.props
  return (
   <div>
    {
     view == 'login'
     ? (<Login changeView={this.changeView}/>)
     : (<Signup changeView={this.changeView}/>)
    }
   </div>
  )
  
 }
}

class Signup extends React.Component {
 ...
 render(){
  const { changeView } = this.props;
  <div className="Signup">
   {/* Signup Form Here */}
   <p>Already registered?</p>
   {/* Wrapping the event in arrow function to avoid auto invoke */}
   <button onClick={() => changeView('login')}>Login</button>
  </div>
 }
 ...
}

class Login extends React.Component {
 ...
 render(){
  const { changeView } = this.props;
  <div className="Login">
   {/* Login Form Here */}
   <p>No account yet?</p>
   <button onClick={() => changeView('signup')}>Sign up</button>
  </div>
 }
 ...
}
```

If there are more than 2 views you can wrap the return in a normal If statement, or move it in a separate method.

or you can use a dynamic component rendering, something like this:

```
    render() {
        const { view } = this.state;

        const ViewComponent = require(`./views/${view}.jsx`);
        return (<div><ViewComponent.default changeView={this.changeView} /></div>);

    }
```